# Linux - SSH - Permission denied. Please try again

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions

I set up a linux server and created a new user. When trying to connect to the server via user@ip i get the message `Permission denied. Please try again.` after entering the password.

When logging in via `su - user` from my user this works without problems, so the password schould be correct.

I checked if the user is locked which is not the case.

I also checked the sshd_config: `PasswordAuthentication yes`.

I also tried adding the user to AllowedUsers: `AllowUsers my_user user`

All of this didn't work.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Ah, thanks, that was the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `AllowUsers …` was there before and you only added `user` to the line, you should reload `sshd`. Without reloading the old config still applies, so the old `AllowUsers …` line restricts you from logging in as `user`.

With `systemd` you reload the configuration of SSH server like this:

```
systemctl reload ssh.service
```

(restarting the server will also work).

Answer (score 0):

A had the similar issue.

Heres what I found out and solved my issue:

I had edit the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

I had to ***uncomment***:

```
"#PermitRootLogin yes"
```

and

```
"#PublicAuthentication yes"
```

and had to ***comment***:

```
"#PasswordAuthentication yes"
```

Then had to erase the old ssh keys:

```
rm -rf /home/user/.ssh
```

Then did:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.104
```

This solved my issue, I created a new ssh fingerprint key, then was asked to enter the login password of the host remote machine.