# Configure SSH to immediately deny all authentication but still listen

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, security, openssh

I'm trying to configure an SSH server to only allow access for a specific user from a specific IP address. I've configured that with

```
PubkeyAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM no

Match User ubuntu Address 192.168.0.58
<tab>PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

I have also deliberately removed the line allowing any other configurations in the other folders in `/etc/ssh/*`, and emptied all of the other configuration directories.

**Expected Behaviour:**
Clients that attempted to connect from IPs not listed in the Match statement would automatically fail with no supported authentication methods because all of them are set to 'no'.

**Actual Behaviour:**
When connecting from an IP outside of the Match statement, the client still prompts for a password. It does not matter if this password is correct, the user is not permitted for entry. Nor is entry permitted with a correct SSH key.

Edit with info (it's spam?)
**INFO:**

- Ubuntu OpenSSH_8.9p1
- SSH Client logs

```
ssh ubuntu@192.168.0.58 -v
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.58 [192.168.0.58] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\whs05/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\whs05/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\whs05/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\whs05/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\whs05/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\whs05/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\whs05/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\whs05/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\whs05/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\whs05/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.0.58:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:7dEDHYt6C/gtbmNlBE3xp8YqvKIcP3b5Nz7JM9MzrWw
debug1: Host '192.168.0.58' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\whs05/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\whs05/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\whs05/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\whs05/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\whs05/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\whs05/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com (unrecognised)
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue:
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\whs05/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\whs05/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\whs05/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\whs05/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\whs05/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue:
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
ubuntu@192.168.0.58's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue:
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
ubuntu@192.168.0.58's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue:
```

- Output of `sudo sshd -T`

```
port 22
addressfamily inet
listenaddress 0.0.0.0:22
usepam no
logingracetime 120
x11displayoffset 10
maxauthtries 6
maxsessions 10
clientaliveinterval 0
clientalivecountmax 3
streamlocalbindmask 0177
permitrootlogin no
ignorerhosts yes
ignoreuserknownhosts no
hostbasedauthentication no
hostbasedusesnamefrompacketonly no
pubkeyauthentication no
kerberosauthentication no
kerberosorlocalpasswd yes
kerberosticketcleanup yes
gssapiauthentication no
gssapicleanupcredentials yes
gssapikeyexchange no
gssapistrictacceptorcheck yes
gssapistorecredentialsonrekey no
gssapikexalgorithms gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-group14-sha1-,gss-gex-sha1-
passwordauthentication no
kbdinteractiveauthentication no
printmotd no
printlastlog yes
x11forwarding yes
x11uselocalhost yes
permittty yes
permituserrc yes
strictmodes yes
tcpkeepalive yes
permitemptypasswords no
compression yes
gatewayports no
usedns no
allowtcpforwarding yes
allowagentforwarding yes
disableforwarding no
allowstreamlocalforwarding yes
streamlocalbindunlink no
fingerprinthash SHA256
exposeauthinfo no
pidfile /run/sshd.pid
modulifile /etc/ssh/moduli
xauthlocation /usr/bin/xauth
ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
macs umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
banner none
forcecommand none
chrootdirectory none
trustedusercakeys none
revokedkeys none
securitykeyprovider internal
authorizedprincipalsfile none
versionaddendum none
authorizedkeyscommand none
authorizedkeyscommanduser none
authorizedprincipalscommand none
authorizedprincipalscommanduser none
hostkeyagent none
kexalgorithms curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
casignaturealgorithms ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
hostbasedacceptedalgorithms ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
hostkeyalgorithms ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
pubkeyacceptedalgorithms ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
loglevel DEBUG
syslogfacility AUTH
authorizedkeysfile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2
hostkey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
hostkey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
hostkey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
acceptenv LANG
acceptenv LC_*
authenticationmethods any
subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
maxstartups 10:30:100
persourcemaxstartups none
persourcenetblocksize 32:128
permittunnel no
ipqos lowdelay throughput
rekeylimit 0 0
permitopen any
permitlisten any
permituserenvironment no
pubkeyauthoptions none
```

Comment: I don't believe what you want is actually possible. It appears that `Match User ubuntu Address 192.168.0.58`, is meant to only allow the user `Ubuntu` to connect from `192.168.0.58` but NOT necessary block all other users. It's an explicit permit not an implicit deny all. You can try `Match User Ubuntu,!*` instead which should allow `ubuntu` but not any other user. Configuring your firewall likely would be an easier task.

Comment: Also from the manual, "For each keyword, the first obtained value will be used.", so break up the Match User and Match Address lines. You also need [Match All](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67334/openssh-how-to-end-a-match-block/303982#303982) so the current behavior might be a configuration syntax issue.

Comment: The info from [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/478801/ssh-allowusers-from-particular-network) might be useful. See also [this post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/ssh-deny-all-users-except-one-277288/).

Comment: I'll give both of these a go. It's strange because even without the Match statement, I would have expected the SSH server to respond with "no supported authentication methods" if all of the supported methods are set to no. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Your `Match` is indeed [in the wrong place](https://superuser.com/a/1730943/432690), but this does not explain the issue. The empty list after `Authentications that can continue:` suggests the server works as expected. I *suspect* the problem is in the *client*, I mean the client tries few methods anyway, despite having received the empty list. This is just my guess though.

Comment: [RFC 4252](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4252): "While there is usually little point for clients to send requests that the server does not list as acceptable, sending such requests is not an error, and the server SHOULD simply reject requests that it does not recognize." – I think this means a client may behave like your client and *there is nothing the server can do to prevent this*. Why is this a problem in your case? In your try the server did not authenticate the client. It's a problem of a client, since *it* chooses to waste its time by trying methods not listed as acceptable.

Comment: Interesting - what I expected as behaviour is NOT actually the expected behaviour. I.e. me expecting it to automatically fail because no supoorted methods were available, is not how my SSH client behaves with just a regular ```ssh ubuntu@ip-goes-here```. Thanks, that clarifies this.